# Chaitin's constant and coding undecidable propositions in a number

Tags: algorithms, computability, information-theory, computational-mathematics, turing-machines

[Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant) $\Omega$ is a constant whose [digits](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChaitinsConstant.html) are defined to [encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant#Definition) the solution to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) and hence $\Omega$ is [uncomputable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). I am not particularly familiar with the field of [algorithmic information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_information_theory), and I have a question about a statement which I once read (by a [physicist](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/mathphyseng.html)) in a [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~christos/classics/Deutsch_quantum_theory.pdf) by [David Deutsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Deutsch):

> If the dynamics of some physical system did depend on a function not in $C(T)$ [the set of [computable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function)], then that system could in principle be used to compute the function. *Chaitin (1977) has shown how the truth values of all ‘interesting’ non-Turing decidable propositions of a given formal system might be tabulated very efficiently in the first few significant digits of a single physical constant* [Emphasis mine].

I have read the [paper](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/ibm.pdf) referenced, and I think I understand (a fair bit of) it, but I still do not understand exactly where the italicized statement comes from; I could not seem to find relevant results in the paper. Would anybody be able to explain exactly where the statement that all of a [formal system's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) ‘interesting’ [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) propositions can be efficiently tabulated in a [real number's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) first few significant digits comes from, how such tabulation would proceed, and what (if any) is the relation of this to [$\Omega$](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_13/papers/brendan.pdf) and [Chaitin's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Chaitin) work?

Comment: Haven't followed your links so I don't know if they are taking the same approach, but I think the idea is to follow Chaitin's construction but instead of a prefix-free coding of Turing machines use a prefix-free coding of a first-order theory, and instead of counting halting programs, count provable formulas, weighting them with the same $2^{-\vert x \vert}$.  Then the resulting real number can be interpreted as a "provability probability" and the first $n$ bits of it can be used to decide the provability of the first $2^n$ formulas (assuming language is binary).

Comment: @DanBrumleve I see, so Deutsch's statement would then be taken to mean that we simply take a small (why?) number of undecidable propositions to be 'interesting' and require $\log(n)$ bits to encode the result?

Comment: @DanBrumleve Wait, but would the first $n$ bits really give us the first $2^n$ formulae? Each digit has $1$ bit of information which should (?) only let us decide one formula? I thought the bijection between formulae (or Turing machines in the case of $\Omega$) and digits was no better than one-to-one? Have I misunderstood what's going on with $\Omega$ the whole time?

Comment: It's the sane as how the first $n$ bits of $\Omega$ gives us the halting status of all programs shorter than $n$.

Comment: @DanBrumleve Oh yes, I think I see it now. It's because it's prefix-free.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong to say the first $2^n$, the number of programs/formulas you get depends on the coding.

Comment: Thanks for that, I see what you're getting at. Still, it will give us a compression which is where I assume he gets the 'tabulated very efficiently' part from. Would $\log{n}$ bits be the best we could get?

Comment: A time-space trade-off is a way to look at it maybe?  We start by knowing how many n-bit programs halt (formulas can be proved), this information uses about $\log{n}$ bits.  Then we run them all in parallel (start proving every theorem starting from the axioms) until exactly that many of them halt (exactly that many formulas shorter than $n$ have been proven).  Now we know exactly which ones that are shorter than $n$ are halting programs (are provable) and which ones aren't.

Comment: ... should have said "this information uses about $n$ bits" not $\log n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comments:

In a prefix-free coding of first-order arithmetic, instead of writing $\exists\ y\ .\ y*y=x$, we would write something like $\exists\ y\ .\ = * \ y \ y \ x$.  It's also convenient to think about a prefix-free binary language, so assign a binary word to every symbol, for example $\exists \rightarrow 0000$, $x \rightarrow 0001$, etc. in either a fixed-width or prefix-free way so that the symbol boundaries can be decoded.

Now let $L$ be such a binary prefix-free language encoding the formulas of arithmetic and define $\Omega = \sum_{x \in L : \text{Pr}(x)}{2^{-\vert x \vert}}$ where $\text{Pr}$ is the provability predicate for $L$.  $\Omega$ is the probability that an infinite random bit string starts with a theorem.

Given the first $n$ bits of $\Omega$, $\Omega_n = \lfloor \Omega \cdot 2^n \rfloor \cdot 2^{-n}$, we can decide $\text{Pr}(x)$ for any formula $x$ with $\vert x \vert \le n$.  What we do is begin a process of proving all theorems of arithmetic starting with the axioms, keeping track of the total contribution to $\Omega$ from every theorem proved so far.   When that value becomes greater than or equal to $\Omega_n$, which it must eventually, all theorems not longer than $n$ bits have been proved.  At that point we can determine $\text{Pr}(x)$ for any formula $n$ bits or shorter.

It's fun to imagine $\Omega$ appearing as a dimensionless physical constant measurable to thousands of digits, or perhaps engraved on a monolith buried on the moon alongside the axioms of ZFC.  I think it is certainly a paradox that mathematical truth is so "compressible".  One way out is to say that there's no way we can *really* know that the $n$-bit string written on the monolith *really* *is* $\Omega_n$ (supposing even that there is other writing that claims it is equal to $\Omega$, that it was created by the gods, etc.).  There is also the point that it's probably computationally infeasible to wait until all short theorems are proved, so it would be useless.  One thing we might get out of it is a situation like where there are $5$ open problems (formulas that are not known to be theorems and not known not to be) expressible in $n$ bits; after choosing to believe in a particular $\Omega_n$, we might then "know" that exactly $3$ of them are provable, and $2$ are not, but that by itself might get us no closer to discovering which are which.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I would +2 if I could, but I've hit the daily vote limit (MSE does that to you...) so I'll upvote later.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking; I guess by 'interesting' Deutsch meant the theorems that have short statements. The fact that he specifically mentioned them being Turing-undecidable propositions makes me wonder though: in a particular $L$ all of the short theorems might be Turing decidable mightn't they, since Turing decidability and $L$-provability aren't the same thing? Would it be possible to have an $L$ in which all of the short theorems were Turing undecidable, thus bearing out Deutsch's statement, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: He is abusing the term "decidable" a bit since it is not a formula itself that is decidable or not, rather it applies to a proposition with an argument like our provability predicate.

Comment: By the way, I love the idea of the monolith. Deutsch's response in the paper to what you have said about being unable to know that it is $\Omega_n$ is interesting: "Nor, conversely, is it obvious a priori that any of the familiar recursive functions is in physical
reality computable. The reason why we find it possible to construct, say, electronic calculators, and
indeed why we can perform mental arithmetic, cannot be found in mathematics or logic. ...

Comment: ...The reason
is that the laws of physics ‘happen to’ permit the existence of physical models for the operations of
arithmetic such as addition, subtraction and multiplication. If they did not, these familiar operations
would be non-computable functions. We might still know of them and invoke them in mathematical
proofs (which would presumably be called ‘non-constructive’) but we could not perform them....

Comment: ...
If the dynamics of some physical system did depend on a function not in $C(T)$, then that system
could in principle be used to compute the function. Chaitin (1977) has shown how the truth values of
all ‘interesting’ non-Turing decidable propositions of a given formal system might be tabulated very
efficiently in the first few significant digits of a single physical constant.
But if they were, it might be argued, we could never know because we could not check the accuracy
of the ‘table’ provided by Nature. ...

Comment: ...This is a fallacy. The reason why we are confident that the
machines we call calculators do indeed compute the arithmetic functions they claim to compute is not
that we can ‘check’ their answers, for this is ultimately a futile process of comparing one machine
with another: *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes*? The real reason is that we believe the detailed physical
theory that was used in their design. That theory, including its assertion that the abstract functions of
arithmetic are realized in Nature, is empirical."

Comment: Despite what I said "decideable" can refer to a formula, meaning that it or its negation is provable.  But I don't think that's what he means here, because if a short formula is undecidable (has no proof or disproof), the construction will tell us that fact, but it won't tell us its "truth value".  What I think he means is something like "truth values of all 'interesting' propositions of a given formal system (a non-Turing decidable problem)".

Comment: That interpretation of what he meant makes sense. Thanks for the awesome answer!

Answer (score 2):

From: ["On Random and Hard-to-Describe Numbers"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.214.7866&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Charles Bennett:

"Suppose one wishes to solve the halting problem for a particular n-bit program p. The program p corresponds to a particular sequence of n coin tosses having probability 2^−n, and, if it halts, contributes this amount of probability to the total halting probability Ω. Let Ω_n represent the known first n bits of Ω, so that Ω_n < Ω ≤ Ω_n + 2^−n.

In order to decide the halting of p, begin an unending but systematic search
for all programs that halt, of whatever length, running first one program
then another for longer and longer times (cf. Fig. 1) until enough halting
programs have been found to account for more than Ω_n of the total halting
probability. Then either p is among the programs that have halted so far,
or else it will never halt, since its subsequent halting would drive the total
halting probability above its known upper bound of Ω_n + 2^−n. Note that
there is apparently no way of using Ω to solve the halting problem for one
n-bit program without solving the halting problem for all other ≤ n-bit
programs at the same time.

Most of the famous unproved conjectures of mathematics (Fermat’s conjecture, Goldbach’s conjecture, the extended Riemann hypothesis, and, until recently, the four-color problem) are conjectures of the nonexistence of
something, and would be refuted by a single finite counterexample. Fermat’s conjecture, for example, would be refuted by finding a solution to
the equation x^n + y^n = z^n in positive integers with n > 2; Riemann’s
hypothesis by finding a misplaced zero of the zeta function. Such conjectures are equivalent to the assertion that some program, which searches
systematically for the allegedly nonexistent object, will never halt.

Interesting conjectures of this sort are generally sufficiently simple to
describe that they can be encoded in the halting of small programs, a few
thousands or tens of thousands of bits long. Thus only the first few thousand digits of Ω would be needed in principle to solve these outstanding
“finitely refutable” conjectures as well as any others of comparable simplicity that might be thought of in the future."

Comment: With $\Omega$ you can solve any problem in maths : given a sentence S that you would like to know if it's true or not, look at the program enumerating the theorems of ZFC searching for a (dis)proof of S.

Comment: Thanks for this! +1 This is a good and succinct expression of the theorem.